# Python: Write a program that counts positive and negative numbers and computers the average of numbers

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, nested-loops

I saw a similar post, but it included functions, which mine does not.

**Objective**: Write a program that reads an unspecific number of integers, determines how many positive and negative values have read, and computes the total and average of the input values (not counting 0's) while the program will halt at 0.

**ISSUE I AM HAVING**: When using the following test values 
1,
2,
-1,
3

I get the following:

The number of positives: 1 
 
The number of negatives: 2
The total amount of numbers used: 3
The average is 1.33 which is 4 / 3

**It should be:**
The number of positives: 1 
 
The number of negatives: 3
The total amount of numbers used: 4
The average is 1.25 which is 5 / 4

**My Attempt below:**

```
positive_number = 0                    
negative_number = 0                      
average = 0                        
count = 0                          
new_number = 0                     


user_input = eval(input("Enter enter as many integers as you want, 0     will halt: "))
if user_input == 0:
    print("You didn't enter any number, code ended")
else:
  while user_input != 0:
    user_input = eval(input("Enter enter as many intergers as you want, 0 will halt: "))

    if user_input == 0:
        print("You didn't enter any number, code ended")

    elif user_input != 0 and user_input > 0:
        new_number += user_input
        positive_number += 1
        count += 1

    else:
        user_input != 0 and user_input < 0
        new_number += user_input
        negative_number += 1
        count += 1


    average = (new_number / count)
    print("\nThe number of positives:",  positive_number)
    print("The number of negatives:", negative_number)
    print("The total amount of numbers used:", count)
    print("The average is", format(average,".2f"), "which is", str(new_number), "/", str(count))
```

What is causing such error? I can only assume that this is a minor fix?

Comment: Not our issue, but use `int(input())` rather than `eval(input())`

Comment: `user_input != 0` is unneccessary after the `if`

Comment: While I think that 1, 2, -1, 3 are 3 positive and 1 negative value, you don't use the first input for your counting, just for the if-checking. If something is entered, you go to the else part and directly ask for the next number.

Comment: i don't think with that input you should be expecting '1 positive, 3 negative'
Also the line after the else  doesn't do much

But basically you ignore your first input

Comment: I'd initialize `user_input` to some number not 0 and then have the while loop and `int(input())` instead of `eval(input())`

Comment: thank you for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the problems in your code and refactored to trap error conditions and removed unnecessary complications:

```
positive_number = 0
negative_number = 0
average = 0
count = 0
total = 0

user_input = None

while user_input != 0:
    try:
        user_input = int(input("Enter enter as many intergers as you want, 0 will halt: "))
    except ValueError:
        user_input=0

    if user_input > 0:
      total += user_input
      positive_number += 1
      count += 1
    elif user_input<0:
      total += user_input
      negative_number += 1
      count += 1

if count==0:
    print("You didn't enter any number, code ended")
else:
    average = total / count
    print("\nThe number of positives:",  positive_number)
    print("The number of negatives:", negative_number)
    print("The total amount of numbers used:", count)
    print("The average is", format(average,".2f"), "which is", str(total), "/", str(count))
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "will this add 0 to count at the end". Adding 0 to count does nothing... right?

Answer (score 0):

First, the first `if` statement is redundant as you test for `user_input != 0` as the loop condition. Second, the reason it was going wrong was because on your first input you immediately overwrote the value of `user_input`, so I put the reprompt code at the end of the loop. Finally, I cleaned up the `if elif else` statement as this does the exact same with fewer characters. The `print` statement for the closing line is also executed once we pull out of the loop - sinc eby definition that means `user_input == 0`

```
positive_number = 0                    
negative_number = 0                      
average = 0                        
count = 0                          
new_number = 0                     

user_input = eval(input("Enter enter as many integers as you want, 0     will halt: "))
while user_input != 0:
    if user_input > 0:
        new_number += user_input
        positive_number += 1
        count += 1

    else:
        new_number += user_input
        negative_number += 1
        count += 1


    average = (new_number / count)
    print("\nThe number of positives:",  positive_number)
    print("The number of negatives:", negative_number)
    print("The total amount of numbers used:", count)
    print("The average is", format(average,".2f"), "which is", str(new_number), "/", str(count))
    user_input = eval(input("Enter enter as many intergers as you want, 0 will halt: "))

print("You didn't enter any number, code ended")
```

Answer (score 0):

Like it was said in the comments, your first input is getting ignored.  Here is an alternative that should work.  I excluded a few redundant check statements.

```
positive_number = 0                    
negative_number = 0                      
average = 0                        
count = 0                          
new_number = 0
user_input = 1                  

while user_input != 0:
    user_input = eval(input("Enter enter as many integers as you want, 0 will halt: "))

    if user_input == 0:
        print("You didn't enter any number, code ended")

    elif user_input > 0:
        new_number += user_input
        positive_number += 1
        count += 1

    else:
        new_number += user_input
        negative_number += 1
        count += 1

average = (new_number / count)
print("\nThe number of positives:",  positive_number)
print("The number of negatives:", negative_number)
print("The total amount of numbers used:", count)
print("The average is", format(average,".2f"), "which is", str(new_number), "/", str(count))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with your code. First of all, the first number that the user prompts is not being evaluated by the code; it's being overwritten once you get to the while loop. There are multiple ways to fix this, but the best would be along the lines:

> cont = True
>
> while cont is True:
>
> > user_input = int(input("Prompt user"))
> >
> > if user_input == 0:
> >
> > > cont = False

You could do a break statement too, it doesn't matter.

So that takes care of why the first number isn't being read, and why the code thinks there were only 3 inputs (as well as your count being off). Now what about the two negatives? I don't know why you got that. When I inputted the numbers you listed, I got one negative and two positives. Try it again and see if it works now, I suspect you must've mistyped.